# How to .remove() by count

Tags: jquery

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
 if ( $( ".line" ).length > 2 ) { 
  //remove all other div.lines but keep the first 2
 }
```

How do you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".line:gt(1)").remove();
```

You can use Jquery's [gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector. This select that indexes which are **greater than** 1.
See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X7a4Z/1/.

Comment: There is no need to check the number of elements in selection with `:gt(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) function for that. It returns parts of an array.

```
$(".line").slice(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine with old good plain javascript:

```
$(".line").slice(2).remove();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qwQWV/

Or you can use only jQuery:

```
$(".line").filter(':gt(1)').remove();​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.line:gt(1)').remove();
```

or

```
$('.line').each(function(pos) {
    if(pos > 1) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```